# How to call a task in Task Scheduler from a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have seen various articles on how to schedule a Powershell script, but I have not see much of the reverse.  I need to call a manual task in Task Scheduler from my PowerShell script.  I am using Powershell 2.0.  Can anyone show me how to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer below as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way may be to use `schtasks.exe`

```
& schtasks.exe /Run /TN <Name of Scheduled Task>
```

NOTE -- on my Windows 8.1 preview with PowerShell 4.0 there is a `Start-ScheduledTask` cmdlet.